# To retrieve data as xml without header using SIMPLEXMLELEMENT in php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to get output like this-

```
<start>
<sub1>
<one>sam</one>
</sub1>
</start>
```

For this I tried this code-

```
<?php 

include('db.php');

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement();

$abc = $xml->addChild('Start');
$s = $abc->addChild('sub1');
$s->addChild('one','sam');

echo $xml->asXML();

?>
```

But this is not giving me any output.Instead it is giving me error.
Error is as follows-
**`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'SimpleXMLElement::__construct() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given' in D:\xamppnew\htdocs\_acct\trialxml.php:5 Stack trace: #0 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\_acct\trialxml.php(5): SimpleXMLElement->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in D:\xamppnew\htdocs\_acct\trialxml.php on line 5`**

Can anyone guide me how to retrieve the `xml` without `header` using `simplexmlelement` in php or please let me know where I went wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Merge first two lines:  `$abc = new SimpleXMLElement('<Start/>');`

Comment: @splash58..I did it this way `<?php 
include('db.php');
$abc = new SimpleXMLElement('<start/>');
$s = $abc->addChild('sub1');
$s->addChild('one','sam');

echo $abc->asXML();

?>` but it is giving me only the word **sam ** as an output ...It is not even giving me the tags.

Comment: yes - https://eval.in/601246   See page source, or use proper header() or echo `<pre>` before

Comment: @splash58..I don't know what is wrong with my system , I copy pasted the same code which you have provided the link to ,but it is still giving me "sam" as output...Do you have any idea about what may be wrong?

Comment: At the begginig of script `header("Content-type: text/xml");`

Comment: @splash58...Can you let me know what should I do if I want to retrieve data from database and then put them into the tags ...Actually I have done that but because of this header it is giving me an error like this-`This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.`

Comment: it's because you write to output something after echo xml.Don't do it. Only xml content

Comment: Got it ..Thanks again ..@splash58

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the url of XML:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('http://example.org/document.xml', NULL, TRUE);
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $xml->asXML();
```

or create a new one:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
```

[php doc](http://php.net/manual/es/simplexmlelement.construct.php)

Comment: Not giving me the desired output @Daniel Guerrero

Comment: Write `Header('Content-type: text/xml');` before `echo $xml->asXML()`

Comment: yeah i got that ...splash58 already answered that..anyways thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML can not work with an empty document. So you will need to load an document with the document element.

```
$Start = new SimpleXMLElement('<Start/>');
$s = $Start->addChild('sub1');
$s->addChild('one','sam');

echo $xml->asXML();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but someone already answered the question... @ThW